# How to find duplicates within each multiline cell against a range of multiline and single line cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I am a novice with Google sheet, please pardon my ignorance. I inherited a data sheet that I am trying to improve. It's a massive data that continues to grow each day.

The daily task: I receive a list of phone numbers that I register online. We use a Google sheet to track all the numbers we are registering for each client of ours. In the sheet I have a column with the phone numbers of each client. These are separated by line breaks within each cell.

​[image]

How am I able to highlight or know which individual numbers within the cells are duplicated? Is that even possible with a multiline cell?

Answer (score 0):

In the end you will still want to get a cell with phone numbers that are all different from each other.
For this reason I propose you a solution different from the one you asked ... a new cell B2 that contains only the unique numbers of cell A2 with this calculation:

```
=join(char(10),sort(unique(transpose(split(A2,char(10))))))
```

**p.s.** *the SORT () function is not essential ... I inserted it because I preferred an ordered result*
[image: dedupe]

Comment: Thank you so much for this formula! Very useful. 

However, what I am encountering is the same client continuously requesting multiple times (on different days)  either the same exact set of numbers or a few new numbers  previously requested sets. 

Example:  John requests 1234, 5678, 9876, on another date John requests 1234,5678, 5555… he previously requested the first two numbers, and only the third one is new. This unfortunately happens very frequently and it’s thousands of multiline numbers within each cell against other cells that contain multiple numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Copy the "deduped" cell and paste it (paste special, values ​​only) into the "phone numbers" cell. No numbers will be lost and there will be no duplicates.